# Scraping some boilerplate

Tags: haskell

How can I achieve this?

```
data SumTerm = 
     St_TotalSum TotalSum
    |St_SumInS SumInS
    |St_SumInT SumInT
    |St_HTerm HTerm

data Monomial  = Monomial {
    mSumTerm :: SumTerm,
    xPower :: Int,
    yPower :: Int,
    coefficient :: Int
    }

newtype Polynomial = Polynomial [ Monomial ]

{- Ok, here I'm lost, VERY lost -}
toMonomial :: (forall {- a which can be in a SumTerm constructor -} ) 
              => a -> SumTerm
toMonomial sum_term = ....
```

This solution of course comes to my mind:

```
class ToSumTerm a where
     toSumTerm :: a -> SumTerm 

instance ToSumTerm TotalSum where
     toSumTerm total_sum = St_TotalSum total_sum
instance ToSumTerm SumInS where
     toSumTerm sum_in_s = St_SumInS sum_in_s
...

toMonomial :: ToSumTerm a => a -> Monomial 
toMonomial x = Monomial ( toSumTerm a ) 0 0 1
```

but it doesn't scale automatically to the constructors of SumTerm. Is there a simple way of not having to write the instances by hand, or even better and if possible, not even the class `ToSumTerm`? In other words, is there some syntax that allows to scrap the boilerplate instance definitions (or achieve an equivalent effect)? If there is a solution, it can imply of course any GHC extensions, like GADTs.

Comment: Is there ever a part in your code where you need to pattern match over `SumTerm`? If there is not, I think both the type class and the ADT version should end up scaling linearly with the number of cases.

Comment: @missingno I agree: if I'm lucky everything will scale linearly... but just for the sake of curiosity I would like to know if there is a better way. By the way, what do you mean by ADT vs(?) type class?

Comment: Minor suggestion is to have typeclass `ToMonomial` with `toMonomial :: a -> Monomial` as its member.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SumTerm` data type is doing nothing at all here, since its just wrapping one level of stuff. It could equally well be `SumTerm a` or just not exist. Since each Monomial only holds one `SumTerm` which always contains just one of a fixed set of types, you can just do the following.

```
data Monomial a  = Monomial {
    mSumTerm :: a,
    xPower :: Int,
    yPower :: Int,
    coefficient :: Int
    }
```

Now of course once you have a list of heterogenous monomials or the like things get funny again, but its hard to say what the "right" answer more generally is unless I have a greater sense of what you eventually want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My intention is to combine several heterogeneous instances of "Monomial" in a list to form a Polynomial. As you noted, the SumTerm datatype is just hiding the the concrete type. My question can be rephrased as "is there some syntax that allows to scrap the boilerplate instances definitions?"... edited accordingly.

Comment: @dsign do you use `TotalSum`, `SumInS, etc on their own ever? The other option is to inline them into the `SumTerm` type to begin with...